# How to Zoom In and Out of the JtextArea in a notepad

Tags: java, swing, zooming, notepad

I am making a notepad using java swing GUI and I am kind of stuck in the zoom in and out part and have looked at so many websites that claim that they have the answer but every time I get out of the website with no knowledge of the subject. I have made a java class for each menu so that I don't get lost on too many lines of code and here is the main code that I wrote.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit;
import javax.swing.undo.UndoManager;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Notepad implements ActionListener {
    JFrame wind;
    JTextArea textA;
    boolean wordWrapOn = true;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu file, edit, view, help;
    JMenuItem newI, openI,saveI, saveAsI, printI, exit;
    Function_File fil = new Function_File(this);
    Function_View function_view = new Function_View(this);
    Function_Edit function_edit = new Function_Edit(this);
    Function_Help function_help = new Function_Help(this);
    JMenuItem iFontArial, iFontCSMS, iFontTNR, iFontSize8, iFontSize12, iFontSize16, iFontSize20, iFontSize24, iFontSize28;
    JMenuItem color1, color2, color3, color4, color5, color6, BColor1, BColor2, BColor3, BColor4, BColor5, BColor6;
    JMenu menuFont, menuFontSize , menuColor, menuBColor;
    JMenuItem iUndo, iRedo, iCut, iCopy, iPaste, iDelete, iSelectAll;
    JMenuItem vHelp,about;
    JMenuItem findAndReplace;
    JMenu zoom;
    JMenuItem zoomIn, zoomOut;
    JCheckBoxMenuItem iWrap;
    UndoManager undoManager= new UndoManager();


    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Notepad();
    }
    public Notepad(){
        createWind();
        createTextA();
        createMenuBar();
        createFileM();
        createViewMenu();
        createEditMenu();
        createHelpMenu();
        function_view.selectedFont = "Arial";
        function_view.createFont(16);
        function_view.wordWrap();
        wind.setVisible(true);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\473800-512.png");
        wind.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
    }

    public void createWind(){
        wind = new JFrame("Notepad");
        wind.setSize(700, 740);
        wind.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public void createTextA(){
        textA = new JTextArea();
        textA.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(e -> undoManager.addEdit(e.getEdit()));
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textA, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        wind.add(scrollPane);
    }
    public void createMenuBar(){
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        wind.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        
        file = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(file);

        edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuBar.add(edit);

        view = new JMenu("View");
        menuBar.add(view);

        help = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(help);
    }
    public void createFileM(){
        newI = new JMenuItem("New");
        newI.addActionListener(this);
        newI.setActionCommand("New");
        file.add(newI);
        newI.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\134224-16.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToNew = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        newI.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToNew);

        openI = new JMenuItem("Open");
        openI.addActionListener(this);
        openI.setActionCommand("Open");
        file.add(openI);
        openI.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\352375-16.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToOpen = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        openI.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToOpen);

        saveI = new JMenuItem("Save");
        saveI.addActionListener(this);
        saveI.setActionCommand("Save");
        file.add(saveI);
        saveI.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\1608823-16.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToSave = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        saveI.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToSave);

        saveAsI = new JMenuItem("Save As");
        saveAsI.addActionListener(this);
        saveAsI.setActionCommand("Save As");
        file.add(saveAsI);
        saveAsI.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\1608823-16.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToSaveAs = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        saveAsI.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToSaveAs);

        printI = new JMenuItem("Print");
        printI.addActionListener(this);
        printI.setActionCommand("Print");
        file.add(printI);
        printI.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\172530-16.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToPrint = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        printI.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToPrint);

        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        exit.setActionCommand("Exit");
        file.add(exit);
        exit.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\3005766-16.png"));
    }

    public void createEditMenu(){
        iUndo = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        iUndo.addActionListener(this);
        iUndo.setActionCommand("Undo");
        edit.add(iUndo);
        iUndo.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\2931166-16.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToUndo = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        iUndo.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToUndo);

        iRedo = new JMenuItem("Redo");
        iRedo.addActionListener(this);
        iRedo.setActionCommand("Redo");
        edit.add(iRedo);
        iRedo.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\2931165-16.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToRedo = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        iRedo.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToRedo);

        iCut = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction());
        iCut.addActionListener(this);
        iCut.setText("Cut");
        iCut.setActionCommand("Cut");
        edit.add(iCut);
        iCut.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\352286-16.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToCut = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        iCut.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToCut);

        iCopy = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction());
        iCopy.addActionListener(this);
        iCopy.setText("Copy");
        iCopy.setActionCommand("Copy");
        edit.add(iCopy);
        iCopy.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\2849804-16.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToCopy = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        iCopy.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToCopy);

        iPaste = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction());
        iPaste.addActionListener(this);
        iPaste.setActionCommand("Paste");
        iPaste.setText("Paste");
        edit.add(iPaste);
        iPaste.setVisible(true);
        iPaste.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\326599-16.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToPaste = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        iPaste.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToPaste);

        iDelete = new JMenuItem("Delete");
        iDelete.addActionListener(this);
        iDelete.setActionCommand("Delete");
        edit.add(iDelete);
        iDelete.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\3669361-16.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToDelete = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        iDelete.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToDelete);

        iSelectAll = new JMenuItem("Select All");
        iSelectAll.addActionListener(this);
        iSelectAll.setActionCommand("Select All");
        edit.add(iSelectAll);
        iSelectAll.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\5760429-16.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToSelectAll = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        iSelectAll.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToSelectAll);

        findAndReplace = new JMenuItem("Find & Replace");
        findAndReplace.addActionListener(this);
        findAndReplace.setActionCommand("Find & Replace");
        edit.add(findAndReplace);
        findAndReplace.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\find-and-replace.png"));
        KeyStroke keyStrokeToFAR = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_H, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        findAndReplace.setAccelerator(keyStrokeToFAR);
    }

    public void createHelpMenu(){
        vHelp = new JMenuItem("Help");
        vHelp.addActionListener(this);
        vHelp.setActionCommand("Help");
        help.add(vHelp);
        vHelp.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\3669173-16.png"));

        about = new JMenuItem("About Notepad");
        about.addActionListener(this);
        about.setActionCommand("About Notepad");
        help.add(about);
        about.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\2931180-16.png"));
    }

    public void createViewMenu(){
        iWrap = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Word Wrap : OFF");
        iWrap.addActionListener(this);
        iWrap.setActionCommand("Word Wrap");
        view.add(iWrap);

        zoom = new JMenu("Zoom");
        zoom.addActionListener(this);
        zoom.setActionCommand("Zoom");
        zoom.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\326690-16.png"));
        view.add(zoom);

        zoomIn = new JMenuItem("Zoom In");
        zoomIn.addActionListener(this);
        zoomIn.setActionCommand("Zoom In");
        zoomIn.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\3643761-16.png"));
        zoom.add(zoomIn);

        zoomOut = new JMenuItem("Zoom Out");
        zoomOut.addActionListener(this);
        zoomOut.setActionCommand("Zoom Out");
        zoomOut.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\3643760-16.png"));
        zoom.add(zoomOut);

        menuFont = new JMenu("Font");
        view.add(menuFont);
        menuFont.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\1608890-16.png"));

        iFontArial = new JMenuItem("Arial");
        iFontArial.addActionListener(this);
        iFontArial.setActionCommand("Arial");
        menuFont.add(iFontArial);

        iFontCSMS = new JMenuItem("Comic Sans MS");
        iFontCSMS.addActionListener(this);
        iFontCSMS.setActionCommand("Comic Sans MS");
        menuFont.add(iFontCSMS);

        iFontTNR = new JMenuItem("Times New Roman");
        iFontTNR.addActionListener(this);
        iFontTNR.setActionCommand("Times New Roman");
        menuFont.add(iFontTNR);

        menuFontSize = new JMenu("Font Size");
        view.add(menuFontSize);
        menuFontSize.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\451442-16.png"));

        iFontSize8 = new JMenuItem("8");
        iFontSize8.addActionListener(this);
        iFontSize8.setActionCommand("size8");
        menuFontSize.add(iFontSize8);

        iFontSize12 = new JMenuItem("12");
        iFontSize12.addActionListener(this);
        iFontSize12.setActionCommand("size12");
        menuFontSize.add(iFontSize12);

        iFontSize16 = new JMenuItem("16");
        iFontSize16.addActionListener(this);
        iFontSize16.setActionCommand("size16");
        menuFontSize.add(iFontSize16);

        iFontSize20 = new JMenuItem("20");
        iFontSize20.addActionListener(this);
        iFontSize20.setActionCommand("size20");
        menuFontSize.add(iFontSize20);

        iFontSize24 = new JMenuItem("24");
        iFontSize24.addActionListener(this);
        iFontSize24.setActionCommand("size24");
        menuFontSize.add(iFontSize24);

        iFontSize28 = new JMenuItem("28");
        iFontSize28.addActionListener(this);
        iFontSize28.setActionCommand("size28");
        menuFontSize.add(iFontSize28);

        menuColor = new JMenu("Color");
        menuColor.addActionListener(this);
        menuColor.setActionCommand("Color");
        view.add(menuColor);
        menuColor.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\6140920-16.png"));

        color1 = new JMenuItem("Gray");
        color1.addActionListener(this);
        color1.setActionCommand("Gray");
        menuColor.add(color1);

        color2 = new JMenuItem("Black");
        color2.addActionListener(this);
        color2.setActionCommand("Black");
        menuColor.add(color2);

        color3 = new JMenuItem("Blue");
        color3.addActionListener(this);
        color3.setActionCommand("Blue");
        menuColor.add(color3);

        color4 = new JMenuItem("Red");
        color4.addActionListener(this);
        color4.setActionCommand("Red");
        menuColor.add(color4);

        color5 = new JMenuItem("Green");
        color5.addActionListener(this);
        color5.setActionCommand("Green");
        menuColor.add(color5);

        color6 = new JMenuItem("White");
        color6.addActionListener(this);
        color6.setActionCommand("White");
        menuColor.add(color6);

        menuBColor = new JMenu("Background Col.");
        menuBColor.addActionListener(this);
        menuBColor.setActionCommand("Background Col.");
        view.add(menuBColor);
        menuBColor.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moatassim\\Downloads\\4243299-16.png"));

        BColor1 = new JMenuItem("gray");
        BColor1.addActionListener(this);
        BColor1.setActionCommand("gray");
        menuBColor.add(BColor1);

        BColor2 = new JMenuItem("black");
        BColor2.addActionListener(this);
        BColor2.setActionCommand("black");
        menuBColor.add(BColor2);

        BColor3 = new JMenuItem("blue");
        BColor3.addActionListener(this);
        BColor3.setActionCommand("blue");
        menuBColor.add(BColor3);

        BColor4 = new JMenuItem("red");
        BColor4.addActionListener(this);
        BColor4.setActionCommand("red");
        menuBColor.add(BColor4);

        BColor5 = new JMenuItem("green");
        BColor5.addActionListener(this);
        BColor5.setActionCommand("green");
        menuBColor.add(BColor5);

        BColor6 = new JMenuItem("white");
        BColor6.addActionListener(this);
        BColor6.setActionCommand("white");
        menuBColor.add(BColor6);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        switch (command) {
            case "New" -> fil.newFile();
            case "Open" -> fil.open();
            case "Save" -> fil.save();
            case "Save As" -> fil.saveAs();
            case "Exit" -> fil.exit();
            case "Word Wrap" -> function_view.wordWrap();
            case "Arial" -> function_view.setFont("Arial");
            case "Comic Sans MS" -> function_view.setFont("Comic Sans MS");
            case "Times New Roman" -> function_view.setFont("Times New Roman");
            case "size8" -> function_view.createFont(8);
            case "size12" -> function_view.createFont(12);
            case "size16" -> function_view.createFont(16);
            case "size20" -> function_view.createFont(20);
            case "size24" -> function_view.createFont(24);
            case "size28" -> function_view.createFont(28);
            case "Gray" -> function_view.changeColor("Gray");
            case "Black" -> function_view.changeColor("Black");
            case "Blue" -> function_view.changeColor("Blue");
            case "Red" -> function_view.changeColor("Red");
            case "Green" -> function_view.changeColor("Green");
            case "White" -> function_view.changeColor("White");
            case "gray" -> function_view.changeBColor("Gray");
            case "black" -> function_view.changeBColor("Black");
            case "blue" -> function_view.changeBColor("Blue");
            case "red" -> function_view.changeBColor("Red");
            case "green" -> function_view.changeBColor("Green");
            case "white" -> function_view.changeBColor("White");
            case  "Undo" -> function_edit.undo();
            case "Redo" -> function_edit.redo();
            case "About Notepad" -> function_help.createAbout();
            case "Help" -> function_help.createHelp();
            case "Delete" -> function_edit.delete();
            case "Select All" -> function_edit.selectAll();
            case "Print" -> fil.print();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) The best way to 'zoom' a text area is to increase the size of the font. 2) People are unlikely to read that code dump, especially given most of it is irrelevant to the problem. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I understand thanks for your advice sir!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you actually want to apply the zoom (zoom factor from menu selection, from Mouse Wheel, or whatever) but I will try to provide the means to do this via the mouse wheel. That is rather, the keyboard <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is **held down** and the Mouse Wheel is scrolled in either up (zoom up) or down (zoom down).

Here is your **createTextA()** method. I have added a MouseWheel Listener to to the JScrollPane for the JTextArea component:

```
public void createTextA() {
    textA = new JTextArea();
    textA.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(e -> undoManager.addEdit(e.getEdit()));
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textA, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.addMouseWheelListener(new java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent evt) {
            if (evt.isControlDown()) {
                textA.setFont(new java.awt.Font(textA.getFont().getFontName(), textA.getFont().getStyle(),
                                           evt.getUnitsToScroll() > 0 ? textA.getFont().getSize() - 2 
                                           : textA.getFont().getSize() + 2));
            }
        }
    });
    scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    wind.add(scrollPane);
}
```

**How does this work:**

Quite simply, it changes the font size for the JTextArea component. The mouse wheel listener is applied to the JScrollPane which is home for the JTextArea component so as to not interfere with the normal scrolling process for the JTextArea which **can** happen if directly applied to the JTextArea component itself.

The [Ternary Operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-Ternary-Operator-Examples) used within the **mouseWheelMoved** event merely determines whether or not the font is increased or decreased dependent upon the direction of the mouse wheel scroll.